# How to pass argument to Docker file ( specifically to FROM instruction)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am trying to make ubuntu version as argument and value should get from docker-compose file.

compose-file:

```
version: '2'
services:
 rahul:
  container_name: rahul_container
  build :
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
   args:
    - uv=ubuntu:16.04
  image : rahul_image
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ARG uv
FROM $uv
```

Output: ERROR: Service 'rahul' failed to build: Error parsing reference: "$uv" is not a valid repository/tag

looks like value is not getting replaced.
tried with FROM "${uv}" but same error

Comment: You can write a script that will create a Dockerfile with what you want in `FROM`, but what is the point?

Comment: Environment variables [aren't supported by the FROM instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement), so presumably ARG variables aren't either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @user2915097. 
I have created shell script which will create docker file and place the arguments which i wanted...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
gcc_v=$2
echo $gcc_v
g_v=0
cat > Dockerfile <<EOL
FROM $1
EOL
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   g_v=$((g_v+1))
   if [[ ($g_v == 14) ]]; then
        echo "$line$2" >> Dockerfile
   else
      echo "$line" >> Dockerfile
   fi
done < "docker_gcc"
docker build -t mygccapp .
```

$ ./tesh.sh ubuntu.16.04 6.3.0

Output:
Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
.
.
.
```